# How to pass Array of Points(x,y) to web services?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, web-services

I am creating an array of `Point(x,y)` using Javascript, `MyAreas` which contain `MyAreas[0].x` and `MyAreas[0].y`. Now I want to pass this array into WebServices. How do I do?

Comment: is the points array in javascript?

Comment: @Leo Cai: Yes it in Javascript. var MyAreas = []; and Adding values like - MyAreas.push({ x: mouseX, y: mouseY });

Comment: Well, you could `JSON.stringify(MyAreas)` to get a JSON String representing your data - it really depends what the webservice is expecting

Answer (score 1):

if you use AJAX to post your items:

```
$.post("myUrl", {points: MyAreas}, function() {
    // callback
});
```

And in C#:

```
public void SavePoints(Points[] points) {
    // your implementation
}

public class Point {
    public int x {get;set;}
    public int y {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Ajax to call your webservice?

Assuming you are, it's very easy, like so:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myUrl,
        data: MyAreas,
        success: function(result){
            // success function here
        }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sth. like this:

```
var points=[point1, point2,..., pointn];
var postData="";
points.each(function(i,p){
    postData+="&points["+i+"].x="+p.x;
    postData+="&points["+i+"].y="+p.y;
});
// postData="points[0].x=12&points[0].y=2&points[1].x=2.....";

$.ajax({
  url:"web service url...",
  contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  type:"post",
  data:postData
  success:function(){
    //todo
  }
});
```

If you use asp.net MVC, the default model binder cab parse such a string of postData.

```
Public ActionResult SavePoints(List<Point> points)
{
    ...
}
```